# messages in Outlook only striked out and not deleted

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook

Some of my IMAP accounts in Outlook don't remove the message from the inbox when I delete them. They just grey them out and put a line through them. How do I make them fully delete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up Outlook to hide messages marked for deletion. Click View > Current View > Hide Messages Marked for Deletion.

Keep in mind that if you do so, you need to purge them later. You can either do it manually by going to Edit > Purge Deleted Messages, or automatically.

[Microsoft Office Help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/purge-imap-items-marked-for-deletion-HP010080420.aspx) has more details on how to set up each of these options.

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less normal for an IMAP email account; messages are "Marked for deletion" and must be "Purged" from the IMAP inbox to be permanently removed. Outlook has the ability to hide "messages marked for deletion"; on Outlook's Menu bar, click "View", then "Current View", then "Customize Current View".  On the window that comes up, you should see a button about the middle of the page that says "Filter" (which will likely be "Off"). Click this "Filter" button, then click the "Advanced" tab. The "Find items that match these criteria" window will probably be empty, so we need to make a filter to hide these "Marked for deletion" messages.  Click the "Field" button, slide the mouse cursor down to "All Mail Fields", then to the right to select "IMAP Status".  Set the "Condition" button to say "equals", and set the "Value" button to read "Unmarked".  Click "OK" twice and those strike-through messages should vanish.

Comment: People are more likely to read your question/answer if you format it so it is not a [wall of text](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text). Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) and [edit] your question to add paragraphs and bullet points ...