# cross out deleted items instead of moving to trash - Outlook 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

We have a user who is used to having mail items being crossed out instead of directly moved to trash.
After upgrading her from windows xp (to a new computer) she ofcourse lost this setting.

Is there a way to get this setting back in outlook 2010?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/447748/messages-in-outlook-only-striked-out-and-not-deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can find a setting called 'Mark items for deletion but do not move them automatically' under File > Account Settings > Account Name > Change > More Settings > Deleted Items.

[Source](http://www.neilturner.me.uk/2013/09/19/marking-imap-emails-deleted-outlook-2010.html)

Comment: When I do this the message just dissapears... I suspect it would be a filter issue but I can't find it.

Comment: @HTDutchy It probably is. Try View > Change View > Change from 'Hide Messages' to 'IMAP Messages'